# Docusign PHP problem with inserting certain data

Tags: php, laravel, docusignapi

I have the following problem. I am currently building a system that creates documents. The problem is how can I use the fields?

I have created a Custom Field this I wanted to put in as follows then:

```
$docu = Docusign::createEnvelope(array(
    'templateId'     => '373809c2-de64-43e1-8f41-a810dac4ab45', // Template ID
    'emailSubject'   => 'Demo Envelope Subject', // Subject of email sent to all recipients
    'status'         => 'created', // created = draft ('sent' will send the envelope!)
    'tabs' => array(
        'textTabs' => array(
            array(
                'tabLabel' => 'username',
                'value' => '123 Main St.'
            )
        )
    )
));
```

I have created a custom Field in Docusign
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixz13.png)

Comment: what have you tried? what is desired? share specific problem

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're not including the appropriate custom field attributes.  Here's a how-to guide discussing this concept in [further detail](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/set-envelope-tab-values/) (specifically step 3). You'll need attributes such as the string used to identify the field, and the x and y coordinates to fine tune how it appears on the document.  In the meantime, here is the underlying PHP code that is used by the launcher to set custom field values:

```
/**
 *  Creates envelope definition
 *  Parameters for the envelope: signer_email, signer_name, signer_client_id
 *
 * @param  $args array
 * @param $demoDocsPath
 * @return mixed -- returns an envelope definition
 */
public static function make_envelope(array $args, $demoDocsPath): EnvelopeDefinition
{
    # document 1 (pdf) has tags
    # /sn1/ - signature field
    # /salary/ - yearly salary
    # /legal/ - legal name
    # /familiar/ - person's familiar name
    #
    # The envelope has one recipient.
    # recipient 1 - signer
    #
    # The salary is set both as a readable number in the
    # /salary/ text field, and as a pure number in a
    # custom field ('salary') in the envelope.

    # Salary that will be used.
    $salary = 123000;

    # Read the file
    $doc_name = 'World_Wide_Corp_salary.docx';
    $content_bytes = file_get_contents($demoDocsPath . $doc_name);
    $base64_file_content = base64_encode($content_bytes);

    # Create the document model
    $document = new Document([ # create the DocuSign document object
        'document_base64' => $base64_file_content,
        'name' => 'Salary action', # can be different from actual file name
        'file_extension' => 'docx', # many different document types are accepted
        'document_id' => 1 # a label used to reference the doc
    ]);

    # Create the signer recipient model
    $signer = new Signer([ # The signer
        'email' => $args['signer_email'], 'name' => $args['signer_name'],
        'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1",
        # Setting the client_user_id marks the signer as embedded
        'client_user_id' => $args['signer_client_id']
    ]);

    # Create a sign_here tab (field on the document)
    $sign_here = new SignHere([ # DocuSign SignHere field/tab
        'anchor_string' => '/sn1/', 'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
        'anchor_y_offset' => '10', 'anchor_x_offset' => '20'
    ]);

    # Create the legal and familiar text fields.
    # Recipients can update these values if they wish to.
    $text_legal = new Text([
        'anchor_string' => '/legal/', 'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
        'anchor_y_offset' => '-9', 'anchor_x_offset' => '5',
        'font' => "helvetica", 'font_size' => "size11",
        'bold' => 'true', 'value' => $args['signer_name'],
        'locked' => 'false', 'tab_id' => 'legal_name',
        'tab_label' => 'Legal name']);
    $text_familiar = new Text([
        'anchor_string' => '/familiar/', 'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
        'anchor_y_offset' => '-9', 'anchor_x_offset' => '5',
        'font' => "helvetica", 'font_size' => "size11",
        'bold' => 'true', 'value' => $args['signer_name'],
        'locked' => 'false', 'tab_id' => 'familiar_name',
        'tab_label' => 'Familiar name']);

    # Create the salary field. It should be human readable, so
    # add a comma before the thousands number, a currency indicator, etc.
    $salary_readable = '$' . number_format($salary);
    $text_salary = new Text([
        'anchor_string' => '/salary/', 'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
        'anchor_y_offset' => '-9', 'anchor_x_offset' => '5',
        'font' => "helvetica", 'font_size' => "size11",
        'bold' => 'true', 'value' => $salary_readable,
        'locked' => 'true', # mark the field as readonly
        'tab_id' => 'salary', 'tab_label' => 'Salary'
    ]);

    # Add the tabs model (including the sign_here tab) to the signer
    # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
    $signer->settabs(new Tabs(
        ['sign_here_tabs' => [$sign_here],
        'text_tabs' => [$text_legal,
        $text_familiar,
        $text_salary]]
    ));

    # Create an envelope custom field to save the "real" (numeric)
    # version of the salary
    $salary_custom_field = new TextCustomField([
        'name' => 'salary',
        'required' => 'false',
        'show' => 'true', # Yes, include in the CoC
        'value' => $salary]);
    $custom_fields = new CustomFields([
        'text_custom_fields' => [$salary_custom_field]]);

    # Next, create the top level envelope definition and populate it.
    return new EnvelopeDefinition([
        'email_subject' => "Please sign this document sent from the PHP SDK",
        'documents' => [$document],
        # The Recipients object wants arrays for each recipient type
        'recipients' => new Recipients(['signers' => [$signer]]),
        'status' => "sent", # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
        'custom_fields' => $custom_fields
    ]);
```